# Java EE - Set class to "active"

Tags: java-ee-7

i am new in Java EE development.

My problem is to set the bootstrap navbar class to active, if the user will go to another side.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        Sign Up</a></li>
    <li id="login" class="active"><a href="/login.do">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">
        </span> Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Actual i have set the "Login" Button in the "navbar" to active.

Now i would like to make it possible, that the active Button in the navbar will switch if the user goes to another site. I tried it with javascript but it does not work in my java-ee project.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which UI framework you are using. For JSF you can do something like the followin:

You can check the current view id with the EL expression `#{view.viewId}` and add the styleClass if it matches your expectations:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li styleClass="#{view.viewId == 'login' ? 'active' : ''">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="login" styleClass="#{view.viewId == 'login' ? 'active' : ''">  
        <a href="/login.do">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```